# Really personal info and in very early stage of hiring; how to proceed?

Tags: recruitment, hiring-process, freelancing, personal-questions

I applied to a tech company for remote work. This is a role I'm interested in, and there aren't many similar alternatives for such role.

After the initial technical tests (I scored very high) and before any interactive communication, I'm asked to fill out a form including the following:

- Marital status
- Children - how many
- Date of birth

Not to mention nationality, home address, last 2 employers - their contact numbers, 3 references.

Is this any normal?

I'm thinking of filling out the form partially and saying something like "willing to provide the rest of it in further stages"

Note: I've seen [Contract complete and client now asking for lots of personal info](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/99326/contract-complete-and-client-now-asking-for-lots-of-personal-info) and [Why job applications require lots of personal info and is there anything to do about it?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/84033/why-job-applications-require-lots-of-personal-info-and-is-there-anything-to-do-a). I've never even heard before anyone being asked "how many kids, .."

**EDIT - Company location**

Latin American company with headquarter in San Francisco, California. I don't know what to make out of this.

**EDIT 2**

I've been asked some personal Qs before, "on-passing" when we sat face to face or maybe on the phone. Answered some of them, dodged others. (still - I don't recall my marital status ever asked before) This is too personal, too "bold". I could make some sense out of it if somewhat latter stages of the process. It's like exposing myself to whoever might be behind the curtain - haven't yet exchanged a word with anyone except emails with mostly standard content.

Makes you think "what next - what am I getting onto."

**UPDATE**

I filled out the form partially and had an online meeting as the first step of the interview. I withdrew my application in an email after that interview- didn't think I can do with them.

I'm located in Canada - was going to work from here.

Comment: Please add in what country or region this is? (In many jurisdictions that I know of, it's either illegal to ask or could be asked in theory but they would have to be very sure they aren't using it as the basis of discrimination).

I'm in the UK and have not been asked about marital status or number (if any) of children for many many years. I'm less sure about date of birth though.

Comment: What is your location?

Comment: A country tag would be helpful.  US companies are eager to make sure that they don't have that sort of information so that they can't be accused of using it to discriminate.  Other countries may have different regimes

Comment: Regarding the children question, I've seen it a couple times when applying if I recall correctly

Comment: Asking about kids is one way of testing to see if you are staying in the area or prepared to move easily... Been a common question for years afaik...

Comment: Have you asked them why you need to fill out the form and why they need the information that they are asking for?

Comment: @SolarMike I've been asked whether I can relocate, travel, how many hours/week, work in .. time zone, etc. one can have kids and can travel/relocate or vice versa. What they're doing is too personal -- are they gonna know my circumstances better then  myself do?

Comment: @sf02 no, I haven't. i'm now trying to figure how to deal with this. what i'm wondering most is "what next"!? I don't even know how they conduct the business yet

Comment: @xavierz they will decide how your circumstances fit their needs.. or not...

Comment: What country do you live in, and in what country/state is the office that is handling the hiring process?

Comment: @SolarMike but highly illegal in the USA I suspect they are blindly following  their home country's backwards dodgy HR policies  - I would advise running away from this job offer

Comment: Possible duplicate (or at least highly relevant reading) of [How to dodge/answer when an interviewer asks (legal) personal questions?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/125589/how-to-dodge-answer-when-an-interviewer-asks-legal-personal-questions)

Comment: @seventyeightist your comment isn't strictly true. Almost every UK employer asks for DoB, gender, ethnicity and similar protected characteristics. It is illegal for anyone in the recruitment process to see the information but there is nothing illegal about the company collecting this kind of data (in fact they are encouraged to do so).

Comment: @SolarMike why stop there then? ask abt my sleeping schedule, my eating habits -- anything extreme there, details of my sexual life esply if i'm single, .. these can all effect those "circumstances" they're so eager to interfere with. I'm a professional, and managing my circumstances is part of my work on my side of things

Comment: @xavierz it’s affect not effect...

Comment: @SolarMike great points you're catching

Comment: Have you thought filling "prefer not disclose"? If they won't accept that, then you'll have to make a choice about your _possible_ future there.

Comment: They are hiring to fill a vacancy in some jurisdiction: you will work *somewhere*, be it California or Ecuador or someplace.  Please [edit] your question to tell us where. It's important because rules about this vary widely. Generally the place you will work governs the rules. In USA, and California especially, these questions are not permitted. Companies who improperly ask them are opening up a big pot of trouble for themselves. (Most multinational companies spend lots of time and effort to do this right.)

Comment: Now that you've decided against the company, please name and shame them on Glassdoor (or Twitter).

Answer (score 5):

> Is this any normal?

You mention that this in in Latin America.

It is not rare to be asked those kinds of questions around here. The marriage status is really common. The kids question not so common but also not rare to see now and then.

Perhaps, like someone said in comments, they are just following their HR hiring guide/questions to the letter.

Now, the thing here is that you must decide if you are willing to disclose such information or not. If you feel like not, then you should thank them for their time and move on and continue job-hunting.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that this is Latin America. So, there's a chance that this is Brazil. Therefore, my answer is based on this assumption.

As absurd as it may seem, for some unknown reason, those are questions every company I've ever interviewed for has asked. I don't think they will do anything related to your marital status or how many kids you have, but that's just the way it is.

They ask, for some reason.

Comment: I disagree with that, I'm Brazilian and worked there until this year and I *never* got asked those questions in any interview I had - mind that I'm a young woman so a prime target for those questions if the employer has discriminatory intent - and I was also never allowed to ask those questions in interviews.

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza as I've written in the answer, *I* have been asked about this kind of stuff in virtually every interview. Obviously, your mileage may vary but from talking with colleagues and simply taking a look at LinkedIn I dare to say that most people have a experience very similar to mine.

Comment: Note that I wrote from my PoV as an interviewer *and* interviewee. I was never allowed to ask those questions even in icebreakers due to legal liability reasons and the "some reason" is evident - to assess whether or not you are able to relocate if needed or (if you're a woman) if they need to take into account a potential maternity leave down the line. And even in Brazil you can sue for discrimination, that's why I was never allowed to ask.

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouzaI'm not a lawyer but I believe you were not allowed to ask due to some internal rule of the company that is afraid to *maybe* getting sued. I don't think that in Brazil it is actually against the law to ask this kind of question, different from many other countries. If it were the case, as I wrote in the other comment, I wouldn't see so many people in LinkedIn complaining about exactly this kind of stuff. I'm glad you didn't have to go through this but I know a great deal of people who have to.

Comment: You *can* sue for discrimination, the problem is having evidence for that. I recently saw a few complaints of former classmates in the Whatsapp group, all women of course. Two of them were recently married and were rejected (obviously the employer was considering potential maternity leave in a few months) and one of them evaded the question and was also rejected

Answer (score -2):

**UK answer**

I'm posting this because I think it will be helpful and may explain some of the paperwork you have. However, some aspects might not translate well to your culture.

> After the initial technical tests and before any interactive communication, I'm asked to fill out a form including the following:
>
> - Marital status
> - Children - how many
> - Date of birth
>
> Not to mention nationality, home address, last 2 employers - their contact numbers, 3 references.
>
> Is this any normal?

Yes and no.

It is entirely normal for companies to collect all of this information. Often they ask for full details at an unnecessarily early stage to make sure the information is already sorted out by the time they actually need it.

References are a good example of this. Typically they don't need these until after you are hired but it is standard to ask for this information up front. Annoying, especially because the HR departments that insist on this never act on the information quickly, but not problematic.

Another example is diversity data. Marital status, children, ethnicity, etc. The company may be legally required to collect this data or may be doing so for perfectly benign reasons. In theory this data should be anonymous and only used to identify broad trends within the company.

The key theme is that it is perfectly normal and reasonable for them to ask for these details if they are a trustworthy employer...... but as I'm sure you have noticed an untrustworthy employer could abuse the situation and use it to filter employees in the application process. I don't know how you can avoid this as an applicant, especially because large employers set a precedent for this information to be demanded during the application stage.

On the plus side it is probably a better outcome for you if a company discriminates against you at the application stage than if they offer you a job and then discriminate against you during employment.

Comment: It is illegal in the UK to ask about marital status or children, as these are protected characteristics. See https://www.gov.uk/employer-preventing-discrimination/recruitment#questions-you-cannot-ask-when-recruiting

Comment: ... and yet companies collect diversity information.

Comment: It is illegal to collect the information for recruitment purposes but.... "You can ask someone their date of birth on a separate equality monitoring form. **You should not let the person selecting or interviewing candidates see this form.**" (taken from the page you linked to)

Comment: Very often the "separate" equality monitoring form will be presented to the applicant within the same electronic application form that non-protected data is entered into.

Comment: I believe they can ask in the application as long as it's kept separately from the interviewers and decision makers to avoid it being used to discriminate against you on.